# VIM FZF, searching multiple directories

Tags: plugin-fzf

Using [FZF](https://github.com/junegunn/fzf) in Vim, is it possible to search project directory and a library directory?  For example when executing FZF, it would search directories:

`~/project/` and `~/libs/include`, and provide results.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can specify the command to obtain the input of fzf by using the `fzf#run()` function.
In your case, this can look something like this:

```
call fzf#run({'source': 'find ~/project/ ~/libs/include -type f', 
             \ 'sink':  'edit'})
```

and if you want, you can add a command like this

```
command! FZFLib call fzf#run({'source': 'find ~/project/ ~/libs/include -type f', 'sink':  'edit'})
```

The options of `fzf#run()` are listed on the [fzf homepage](https://github.com/junegunn/fzf#usage-as-vim-plugin)

Answer (score -1):

FZF will search the total pwd. If pwd is `~`, both directories `~/project/` and `~/libs/include` will be searched.

Comment: I'm pretty sure the OP doesn't want FZF to search through all the files in his home directory.

Comment: It's just a solution. And FZF search only one directory once. The two directories can be moved into the same directory. If you don't want to search though all the files in the directory, you can set FZF_DEFAULT_COMMAND with ag or find and ignore options or file to filter the other directories.